# Точка начала анимации CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animation, keyframes

Мне необходимо, чтобы на страничке из её центра вырастал шар (фон в виде шара), но у меня он растёт только из левого верхнего угла.

Пользовался animation @keyframes

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете воспользоваться свойством [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) что бы переопределить точку анимации:

```
transform-origin: center;
```